# Prove a complex number is real

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, analytic-number-theory

Let $z$ be a complex such that $|z-1| =1$, and consider the complex numbers $v$ and $w$ such that: $w = z^2 -z$ and $3\arg(v) = 2\arg(w)$, where arg  is the argument of a complex number. Show that $$ \left({zv\over w}\right)^2$$ is a real number

I first tried to show that the imaginary part of the number is zero, knowing that half of the subtraction of a complex number and its conjugate is equal to its imaginary part. Nonetheless, i could not find a relation between $z$ and $v$, and I ended up in a answer with these two letters.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Real  numbers is a subset of complex numbers so how will we prove that a complex number is a real number.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I may not have written properly my title. What one should prove is that the multiplication and division of three non-real numbers result a real number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for two non real numbers is possible as $i^2=-1$ but it isnt the case for $i^3=-i$ so we cant prove it for three non real numbers also if for a quadratic if roots are imaginary then they exist as conjugates and their product is a real number. Hope this helps you.Let the three numbers be $1+0i,2+0i,-3+0i$ so we directly get the result . I dont think there exists any rigorous way to prove it.REAL numbers are subset of complex numbers hence I have given you this example.